# keep credit Coupon code for a product that is less than the coupon in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We are looking for a way to keep the credits / amount of a coupon code when the coupon code is more then the product. For instance:

Product is 10
Discount is 25
Credits is 15

So if in this case we would like that the customer can use the coupon code for a second time with 15 euro.

Does anyone know if there is something like this for Magento?

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using Magento Enterprise or Magento Go, which both have store credit built in, you'll need an extension to support this functionality.

Look for 'gift card' or 'store credit' extensions. Here are three frequently used ones that are well reviewed that may be of interested to you:

http://www.mageworx.com/customer-credit-magento-extension.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gift-cards.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/gift-voucher.html